# How do I Report Stalking?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I am trying to get most out of stackexchange by asking and answering, and as a human, I do go wrong. I am sure that the right way to point it out is by a downvote, and/or a comment, but then looking up my history, past answers, and downvoting them sequentially is a source of demotivation. I do not want to disclose the name in public, but what I do want to know is how do I get in touch with the right people, and seek help regarding this issue? I do think if this continues, it will be difficult to continue using this very excellent resource....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Like Manish said, a flag would do the job. Meta (like the one you've posed) and chat (of course, our h-bar is always a dead room with alive users) are welcome. BTW, Don't get so tensed by the downvotes. They're just another vote. It will be hard to digest a `-2` in your rep score & a negative vote in your question (which you may think it won't get attention, *it's untrue*). And, we must be happy that we aren't crowded by serial downvoters like in the mother site ;-)

Comment: You should take it not the personally when somebody points out a flaw in your physics reasoning or way of thinking, but consider if the person who points it out is not right. If he is right, try to learn from it and if he is wrong say why he is wrong from a physics point of view. Pointing out flaws in posts on the main thing is a good and encouraged thing. However, as Manishearth says, if you are victim of a serial downvote attack, this will be reverted automatically.

Comment: @Dilaton Note that there is a difference between "pointing out a flaw" and simply saying that a post is wrong in an abrasive manner (especially when other comments that say the same exist). Comments should constructively add to the thread. If it is not constructive or not adding anything, it shouldn't be posted :)

Comment: @Dilaton, I never said he is wrong, I accept the mistake, if any. But, my point is just that, save one or two questions, the others that were downvoted, were already downvoted. So, the fact that he is digging up all my past mistakes is demotivating and distressing. Moreover, it is not that the reason was not mentioned earlier. In fact, I have understood where I have gone wrong, so the further downvote really serves no purpose

Comment: @SaurabhRaje were any of your upvoted answers serially upvoted by this person?

Comment: @LarryHarson, do you mean downvoted in the end of the sentence? If so, I would say no. But the ones that were given ages ago were downvoted now. Moreover, the same reason was given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I Report Stalking?

Custom flagging one of your own posts and mentioning the details is enough. This works too, however it is best to do these things in private.

> but then looking up my history, past answers, and downvoting them sequentially is a source of demotivation.

This is not exactly stalking, though serial downvoting will be reversed. If the comments are constructive, if is OK, but if they are rude or otherwise non constructive, this is not good.

Rest assured, I am looking into it.

Comment: I am sorry if I have used the word stalking incorrectly, I thought this was similar to the meaning....